# Duda sobre foreach con datos de mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array, foreach

Soy nuevo en php y mysql, tengo una base de datos con algunos campos ya creados, la idea es imprimir un ticket como los supermercados pero quiero listar uno por uno los productos comprados, para ello leí que se podía usar foreach, este es el código que tengo

```
foreach ($datos as $productos) {
   echo $productos->product_name ." x ". $productos->quantity; 
 }
```

product_name hace referencia al campo en la bd de los nombres de los productos y quantity la cantidad.

Lo ideal seria que me saliera algo como:

jabón x 1
papas x 2

Y asi, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'product_name' of non-object in

Alguien tiene alguna idea para este muchacho desorientado? gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow @Mauricio, para poder ayudarte con tu problema seria recomendable que pusieras mas código referente a tu problema.

Comment: @Mauricio deberías añadir la parte en la que se asigna valor a `$datos`. y en especial la parte del método que estés utilizando para hacer el _fetch_. Lo más probable es que los datos se estén obteniendo como array y no como objeto y entonces para acceder a ellos deberías hacer `$producto["product_name"]` en lugar de `$productos->product_name` (que lanzaría el error que ves). Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y que completes el [tour] para más información y consejos (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada te aconsejo [leer esto](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) y sin olvidarnos de leer [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php).

Paralelamente te resumo las funciones que utilizarias para la recuperacion e impresion de valores de la base de datos en php, dado que hay 2 metodologias de programacion (Orientada a Procedimientos que se está eventualmente quedando obsoletos y Orientada a Objetos) Dentro de los links, en los ejemplios verás los usos de ambos estilos, las funciones son alias de metodos del objeto mysqli:

Conectar: [mysqli::__construct](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php) (Metodo _construct de la [Clase Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli.php))

Consultar: [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

Recorrer datos y mostrar: [mysqli_stmt::fetch](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Cerrar coneccion: [mysqli::close](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.close.php)

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolví muchas gracias a todos, para aquel que tenga un problema similar acá dejo como lo resolví, muchas gracias de nuevo a todos:

```
<?php 
 <br>
 $imprimir =''; <br>
 foreach ($datos as $productos) { <br>
 $imprimir .= '* '.$productos['product_name'].'<br>';
}
```